# Joomla 3.8 Adding a Custom Registration Check

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla3.8

I'm building a website using Joomla 3.8.0.

I'd like to add a custom question to the registration process.  For example, I'd like to ask them the capital city of Canada and then check upon submit if the answer was Ottawa.  I'd like to do this, if possible,using an extension and not modifying php code within Joomla.

Does anyone know of such an extension?  I've looked through the Joomla extensions directory already, but haven't seen one that seems to do what I want.  Seems they all simply allow custom fields, but not fields that can be reviewed for a specific answer as described above.  Preferably it would be free as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[EasyCalcCheck Plus](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/easycalccheck-plus) will do this for you. It's free. There are probably [others](https://extensions.joomla.org/tags/captcha) too.